# How do I match the file name on the dropzone form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem deleting files, this is because the file names on the dropzone form are different from those in the folder.
and because of this I can't delete the image. but if the image name is the same I can delete it.

[image]

if you ask why does the name change? because I made a name change automatically on my controller.

my controller

```
    public function create(){
        if (!empty($_FILES)) {

            $config['upload_path'] = $this->upload_path;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
            $new_name = time().$_FILES["file"]['name'];
            $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
            $config['width'] = 900;
            $config['height'] = 600;

            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){

                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $foto = $uploadData['file_name'];

            }

        }
public function remove()
    {
        $file = $this->input->post("file");

        if(file_exists($this->upload_path.$file)) {
            unlink($this->upload_path.$file);
        }
    }
    }
```

my javascript

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzoneForm", {
                    url: "<?= base_url() ?>backend/galeri/create",
                    acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    removedfile: function(file) {
                        var name = file.name;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "<?= base_url() ?>backend/galeri/remove",
                            data: { file: name },
                            dataType: 'html'
                        });

                        var previewElement;
                        return (previewElement = file.previewElement) != null ? (previewElement.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement)) : (void 0);
                    }
                });
```

my form

```
<form action="<?= base_url() ?>backend/galeri/create" class="dropzone" id="dropzoneForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Comment: Remove `time().` simplez...

Comment: as i said, i accidentally added time(). okay let's say I don't add time (). try to see my picture. the file I uploaded contains spaces but the upload results change the space to an underscore. this also affected so I can't delete it.